# rendering image with express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im new with node.js and express.js and Im trying to upgrade my front end project with them. I managed to get everything perfect except for my images to load. i have tried all possible solutions that i could find and still no happy ending. My project has a generic express file structure.

my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

example div containing image:

```
<div id="logo" class="col-xs-12">
  <img class="menuClosed" src="http://localhost:3000/images/logoRV.png">
</div>
```

here is the message i get on the terminal:
  "GET /images/logoRV.png 200 0.714 ms - 856"

here is what the inspector tells me in the resources tab:
  "An error ocurred trying to load the resource"

UPDATE: apparently the problem was that i had an alias of the image in that folder instead of the original... after saving the original it rendered correctly. thanks to everybody who tried to help.

Comment: And, where are your images stored on your server hard drive?  When you say you see a message at the "terminal", do you mean on the server computer?

Comment: im using a local server and images are stored in public>images>*here*

Comment: What happens if you just put this URL `http://localhost:3000/images/logoRV.png` directly into the browser URL bar?  What do you see in the browser?  What does the browser console say?  What does the Chrome Network tab show?

Comment: is Safari i get a blue square with a ? sign, no message in its console and in the terminal i get: "GET /images/logoRV.png 200 8.636 ms - 856"... now, in Chrome i get the same this in the browser and in the console: "Navigated to http://localhost:3000/images/logoRV.png"

Comment: What does the Chrome network tab show?  Does it show a 200 status code from the GET?  If so, then your images must be corrupted.  The browser is receiving them, but can't read them.  If not a 200 status code, then what does it show?

Comment: I see you found that you didn't have the right image in the right folder.  I guess you can either delete your question or post your own answer.  Should probably do one or the other to finish off the question so it doesn't just hang here unanswered.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `app.use(express.static('path_to_images)` to load static resources like image. You haven't posted your routes, so it's hard to know what you intend to happen when the router encounters a url like `/images/...` but I'm guessing you just want to serve static images from a directory.

You are currently setting a up a static directory with this line:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

You could just put images in there.

You can also set up directories to serve to specific urls like this:

```
app.use('/images', express.static('photos'))
```

Comment: The OP claims the browser says they are getting a 200 status which means there must be a route that appears to be matching that image.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I wonder what happens when the OP just loads http://localhost:3000/images/logoRV.png in a browser?? I wonder if a route is matching, but not returning an image? It would be helpful to know what's in routes.

Comment: Yeah, I'm a bit confused about what messages are being shown in what location too (thus my comment to the OP).  The only explanation for both the messages they posted if they actually apply to the same request would be that a non-image or corrupted image was getting served by the server, but then couldn't be processed by the browser because it was a bad image.  But, that seems unlikely so probably the info the OP has posted is flawed in some way which is why we are confused.

Comment: in the browser i get a rectangle with a ? sign. apperantly the route is matching because i am not getting any errors from the javascript console. ive tried adding in my app.js those solutions but still no luck... getting a little frustrated! considering going back to PHP XD

Comment: "IF" all the above didn't work... You might need to configure your express headers maybe adding the following could help: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET'); the GET would allow the images to respond to a GET request

Answer (score 2):

If your images are in the folder, say public.

```
project ->
         public
              -> images 
                       -> pic1.jpg
                       -> pic2.jpg
              -> uploads
         index.js
```

You could tell express to use a path for static data.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

You could then specify the path in HTML attr with relative to the public folder.

```
<img name="picture" src="/images/pic1.jpg" class="card-img-profile pro-img" id="picture" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your express server requests the images via a GET request, if you are not getting a response for the images I would suggest revising your **headers** configuration, looking at the solutions above this should have worked already but "if not resolved yet" the following configuration might help:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // change '*' to domain to restrict access to domain only
 res.header(
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
  'Origin, X-Requested-With, ContentType, Accept, Authorization'
 );
 if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
  // This will tell express that GET requests to images should be allowed
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET'); 
  res.status(200).json({});
 }
 next();
});
```

An explanation to file serving can be found here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile